# Magento 2 - Default One page checkout does not work even if enabled

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout

I am working on magento 2.3 CE.

```
Admin >> Store >> Configuration >> Sales >> Checkout >> Checkout Options >> Enable Onepage Checkout >> Yes.
```

One page checkout is enabled. However checkout is still displayed on 2 pages (Shipping and Payment)

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That is magento's definition of one page checkout.  Notice how the controller stays the same when switching between shipping and payment.

This terminology comes from Magento 1 where before 'One page checkout' the checkout was split into multiple steps and separate screens.

One page checkout was added after.  If you are after truly on one page you will have to use an extension.

Google 'Magento 2 One page checkout'.  There are plenty of options.